# Javascript onclick not working as expected in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have link in my page , when user clicks on the link it should give me a dialog box , so to test , i did the following code.

Here is my '**view**' code

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <br>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/unsayd') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                          <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @foreach ($posts as $post)

                                <article class = "post" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
                                    <p>{{$post->userpost}}</p>
                                <div class='info'>
                                    Posted by {{ $post->user->name }} on {{ $post->user->created_at}}
                                </div>

                                 <div class = 'interaction'>
                                    <a href=#>Like </a> |
                                    @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                        |
                                        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                                        <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a>

                                    @endif


                            @endforeach

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="edit-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="post-body">Edit the Post</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="post-body" id="post-body" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-save">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

When the user clicks the edit link

```
<a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

I want to the js onlick function to be called , Here is the JS code

```
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('a').eq(2).on('click' , function(){
console.log('It works');
```

});

When I click the edit button , i dont see anything in the console , but it is supposed to show 'It works'.

This are the scripts included in the main layout

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::to('src/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

app.js is stored in public\src\js\app.js

What is the issue here and what is the possible way to fix the issue ?
NOTE : when i click edit , i can see the app.js is loading in the cmd after running artisan serve.

Comment: wrap the binding code inside dom reaqdy event

Comment: I am a very beginner , can you say it in a beginner way of understanding

Comment: Try this code $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post .interaction a:eq(2)').click(function() {
    console.log('It works');
  });
})

Comment: No , it didn't work

Comment: try this $(document).on("click", '.post .interaction a', function() {
  alert('It works');
});

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is how I got around it:
Here is the view:

```
<button id="testButton" type=""button">Click me</button>
```

Here is the js:

```
$(document).on('click', '#testButton', function () {
    console.log('clicked!');
});
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the script is executed before the element is being rendered. For such situations, you can use the dom ready handler, which will execute whenever the dom is ready,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post .interaction a:eq(2)').click(function() {
    console.log('It works');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- The jQuery code needs to be wrapped in a DOM ready handler, to ensure the elements exist when you try to access them.
- `.eq()` is zero based, so `.eq(2)` would select your delete button not edit. You would need `.eq(1)` for the edit button.

I would rewrite the code to delegate the click to the form, instead of assigning a click to every edit button individually, and since your button has class `edit`, it would be more appropriate to use that instead of `eq()`.

```
$(function(){
    $('form.form-horizontal').on('click', '.post .interaction .edit', function(){
        console.log('It works');
    });
});
```

If you have multiple forms, then give it a unique class or ID and use that in the above.